# How to fix 401 (Unauthorized) for a login request

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm getting a 401 error for my login requests using JWT authentication, on the signup page it's working great and it creates the user in database, but the login is not working.
I really dunno which code to include so feel free to for the needed code.

I verified that entered credentials already exists in the database

login.ts

```
export class LoginComponent {

  public form={
em:null,
pass:null
  };
  public error = null;
    constructor(private http :HttpClient) { 

    }
Submit(){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login',this.form).subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      error => console.log(error)
    );

  }
    }
```

api.php

```php
<?php


Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',


], function () {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
});
```

login function

```php
public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'user does not exist'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
```

Comment: What JWT package you are using? for Tymon/JWTAuth its `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))`

Comment: You need to send the authorized token witch each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an `Authorization` header in your post request:

```
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
```

Instead of sending the authorization header manually in each api call, better option is to use `HttpInterceptor`.

[See this blog for more details](https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors)

Comment: Can you please explain, in this implementation, he gets the token from a local storage but in my case, it's going to create the token upon the login submit so what do i need to do?

Comment: @houssembouallagui Get the token from server and store in localStorage. Don’t include authorization header for this route. On the server side, allow this route to go through without jwt authorization because at this moment you don’t have the token. For all the other routes, follow the answer and the blog.

Comment: Thank you, i've been stuck at this for days